# DataSet does not support System.Nullable<> error on linq

Tags: c#, linq, null

When i run the code i get "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>" error

I tried many thing to eliminate this problem.

Is there any way to rid of this error. please help me.

```
       ///SONRA GEL
        DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
        dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AY", typeof(string)));

        dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("KIMYASAL", typeof(string)));

        dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MIKTAR", typeof(double?)));
        dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MAKINA", typeof(string)));

        dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PRICE", typeof(double?)));



        var result = from dataTable1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                     join dataTable2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                     on dataTable1.Field<string>("KIMYASAL") equals dataTable2.Field<string>("eliaradı")
                     select dtFinal.LoadDataRow(new object[]
         {


            dataTable1.Field<string>("AY"),
            dataTable1.Field<string>("KIMYASAL"),
            dataTable1.Field<double?>("MIKTAR"),
            dataTable1.Field<string>("MAKINA"),
              dataTable2.Field<double?>("PRICE"),
          }, false);
        result.CopyToDataTable();

        MessageBox.Show("finale geldi");

        //   dataGridView1.DataBind();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = dtFinal;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Comment: there is no dataset on the code why i get this error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MIKTAR", typeof(double?)));
```

you define a data column with a nullable type (`double?`). That's not necessary: The DataTable/DataColumn classes support nullability for all data types out of the box (since those classes predate .NET generics and, thus, .NET value type nullability).

In other words:

```
dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MIKTAR", typeof(double)));
```

(`double` instead of `double?`) will work fine, you are *still* able store store `null` in that column.

---

Note: If you explicitly *don't* want to support nullability for a certain column, you need to set the [AllowDBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull?view=netframework-4.8) property to false:

```
 // This column is nullable
 dtFinal.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NullableColumn", typeof(double)));

 // This one isn't
 var col = new DataColumn("NotNullableColumn", typeof(double));
 col.AllowDBNull = false;
 dtFinal.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: hank u for good informations. I deleted "" but then problem is exist... :(

Comment: @UfukYıldırım: You need to fix `PRICE` as well ... same problem. It's not about the data, it's about the DataColumn declaration.

Comment: @UfukYıldırım: If the problem still persists, please update your question with a [mcve].